# Member Group Tabs - Admins being logged out Tab URL

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm having issues with the Member Group Tabs.  My admins are being logged out when they click on menu items.

I think the issue is on the url tab.  I've tried a variety of urls but nothing works.  Not even the example url :

/admin.php?&D=cp&C=design&M=manager

Comment: What version of EE are you using? It looks like there was a recent change where EE logs you out unless the session ID is in the URL. We'll see if we can find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Member Group Tabs v1.2 is now EE 2.6 and above compatible.

https://github.com/surprisehighway/member-group-tabs